# Control Animation Scale

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am learning about CSS animation.

Trying to manipulate the amount of zoom on each animation.

I need the image to zoom-in **less** (not slower) than it is doing so now right and return to its zoom-out state.

**On which** of the CSS properties bellow can I control how much zoom I let it come in and out?

I'd like a scenario where it only zooms in enough to get **barely** out of frame and then right back out.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frame {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://www.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/tnl_redesign_article_landing_page/public/1453920892/DUBAI-554088081-ABOVE0116.jpg?itok=dcoZnCrc');
  -webkit-animation: zoomeffect 10s infinite;
  -moz-animation: zoomeffect 10s infinite;
  animation: zoomeffect 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomeffect {
  0% {
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(2, 2);
  }
  100% {
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomeffect {
  0% {
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(2, 2);
  }
  100% {
    background-position: center;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="frame">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change how far it zooms in by playing with the 50% code in both `@keyframes` classes, I changed it to 1.5. Try values from 1.0 - 2.0 to get the amount of zoom you want.

50%{
        background-position:center;
      transform:scale(1.2,1.2);
    }

```css
.wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid black;
  margin:50px auto 50px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.frame{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-image: url('http://www.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/tnl_redesign_article_landing_page/public/1453920892/DUBAI-554088081-ABOVE0116.jpg?itok=dcoZnCrc');
   -webkit-animation: zoomeffect 10s infinite;
   -moz-animation: zoomeffect 10s infinite;
   animation: zoomeffect 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomeffect{
  0%{
   background-position:center;
    transform:scale(1,1);
  }
  50%{
   background-position:center;
    transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
  }
  100%{
   background-position:center;
    transform:scale(1,1);
  }
}
@keyframes zoomeffect{
  0%{
   background-position:center;
    transform:scale(1,1);
  }
  50%{
   background-position:center;
   transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
  }
  100%{
   background-position:center;
    transform:scale(1,1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="frame">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using Chrome it barely zooms then goes back out, changed it to 1.5 so it is more visible.

Comment: Ahh I see, when you mess with the values in that class it changes the amount it zooms in I believe 2 is 200% so 1.2 would be like 120%(just guessing on the %)

Comment: am not the OP, just simple SO user having trouble to run the code :) but i found the issue ;)

Comment: Thank you Scath! the ( , ) was throwing me off, I didn't know I had to play with it using ( . )

Comment: No problem I think you want about 1.2

Comment: @Scath why (1.5, 1.5) rather than just (1.5) ?

Comment: I just try to modify the least amount of code as possible usually, but either seems to work fine.